# can a delay be set on requestAnimationFrame()?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, requestanimationframe

I have a vert long (i.e. vertically large) page with text in one column and a floating element in the other column. The desired effect is for the floating element to be "chasing" the scroll of the window and eventually (when the scrolling stops) end up back at its original offset from the top of the viewport.

I have the following code working:

```
var ticking = false;
var box = document.getElementById('box1');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  ticking = ticking || requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    ticking = false;
    var top = window.scrollY;
    console.log(top);
    box.style.transform = 'translateY(' + top + 'px)';
    box.style.transition = 'all 100ms ease-out';
  }); 
});
```

```
#left {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: left;
  width: 800px;
  font-size: 200%;
}

#box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```
<div class="outer">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="box1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus pulvinar sodales tortor non laoreet. Etiam facilisis enim nec eros imperdiet, nec ultrices magna ornare. Aliquam eget dictum arcu. Nulla et mauris vel massa venenatis mattis nec in orci. Pellentesque fringilla fermentum gravida. Praesent rhoncus augue sed lacus rutrum, tincidunt ultrices metus consectetur. Mauris pulvinar nec lacus sed interdum. Nullam fermentum massa consequat pretium maximus. Vestibulum ultrices nibh et venenatis pharetra. Quisque ipsum leo, rhoncus quis erat non, suscipit malesuada tellus. Nam commodo, dolor pretium malesuada scelerisque, nisl ante molestie est, in accumsan tortor massa quis lectus. Suspendisse nisi felis, commodo non porta eleifend, auctor at dui. Nullam ullamcorper sodales tortor, laoreet euismod arcu pretium sed.

Sed maximus scelerisque ornare. Quisque pellentesque tincidunt pellentesque. Cras eu convallis felis, sollicitudin bibendum mauris. Nulla volutpat dui in neque eleifend imperdiet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis blandit dictum euismod. Nam elementum metus non fermentum tincidunt. Integer enim mauris, porta eget nibh non, lacinia ornare elit. Proin justo justo, luctus sit amet dui non, feugiat euismod quam. Phasellus ullamcorper, lectus eu vestibulum feugiat, quam turpis egestas velit, ut hendrerit lectus justo a massa. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum varius neque blandit mi posuere tempor.

Suspendisse vitae sem non orci volutpat malesuada ac sit amet odio. Vestibulum faucibus lectus consectetur, rhoncus nisi in, venenatis lorem. Nullam bibendum nisl in enim pellentesque, sed gravida erat scelerisque. Ut scelerisque faucibus felis at posuere. Donec eget iaculis augue. Nunc venenatis elit vitae nisl suscipit, eu interdum tortor dignissim. Morbi ut nisl massa. Integer egestas sed tortor ac vulputate. Pellentesque tempor quam at purus scelerisque molestie. Cras cursus feugiat nulla. Pellentesque congue ligula lectus, nec condimentum magna tincidunt et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer tempor mattis purus aliquet euismod. Suspendisse augue eros, pretium ut cursus eget, dapibus ut risus.

Duis et interdum libero, luctus ultrices ante. Nam vitae justo in nisi tempor mollis. Donec pharetra laoreet felis, in lacinia odio dignissim vitae. Phasellus aliquet, lectus id dignissim lobortis, lectus ipsum mollis massa, vitae semper magna ligula et sapien. Fusce interdum nibh ut purus vehicula porttitor. Vivamus et ante ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis sagittis elit. Curabitur bibendum suscipit enim, consequat varius ante pretium at. Vestibulum malesuada, est eu egestas dapibus, justo odio feugiat sem, id mollis metus est luctus risus. Maecenas vitae purus nulla. Vestibulum eu dolor vel nunc iaculis mollis. Curabitur at eros aliquet, sodales nunc sed, fringilla quam. Aenean odio felis, porta in bibendum vitae, mollis in est. Nam nisi risus, volutpat eu pharetra vel, scelerisque at mauris.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus pulvinar sodales tortor non laoreet. Etiam facilisis enim nec eros imperdiet, nec ultrices magna ornare. Aliquam eget dictum arcu. Nulla et mauris vel massa venenatis mattis nec in orci. Pellentesque fringilla fermentum gravida. Praesent rhoncus augue sed lacus rutrum, tincidunt ultrices metus consectetur. Mauris pulvinar nec lacus sed interdum. Nullam fermentum massa consequat pretium maximus. Vestibulum ultrices nibh et venenatis pharetra. Quisque ipsum leo, rhoncus quis erat non, suscipit malesuada tellus. Nam commodo, dolor pretium malesuada scelerisque, nisl ante molestie est, in accumsan tortor massa quis lectus. Suspendisse nisi felis, commodo non porta eleifend, auctor at dui. Nullam ullamcorper sodales tortor, laoreet euismod arcu pretium sed.

Sed maximus scelerisque ornare. Quisque pellentesque tincidunt pellentesque. Cras eu convallis felis, sollicitudin bibendum mauris. Nulla volutpat dui in neque eleifend imperdiet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis blandit dictum euismod. Nam elementum metus non fermentum tincidunt. Integer enim mauris, porta eget nibh non, lacinia ornare elit. Proin justo justo, luctus sit amet dui non, feugiat euismod quam. Phasellus ullamcorper, lectus eu vestibulum feugiat, quam turpis egestas velit, ut hendrerit lectus justo a massa. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum varius neque blandit mi posuere tempor.

Suspendisse vitae sem non orci volutpat malesuada ac sit amet odio. Vestibulum faucibus lectus consectetur, rhoncus nisi in, venenatis lorem. Nullam bibendum nisl in enim pellentesque, sed gravida erat scelerisque. Ut scelerisque faucibus felis at posuere. Donec eget iaculis augue. Nunc venenatis elit vitae nisl suscipit, eu interdum tortor dignissim. Morbi ut nisl massa. Integer egestas sed tortor ac vulputate. Pellentesque tempor quam at purus scelerisque molestie. Cras cursus feugiat nulla. Pellentesque congue ligula lectus, nec condimentum magna tincidunt et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer tempor mattis purus aliquet euismod. Suspendisse augue eros, pretium ut cursus eget, dapibus ut risus.

Duis et interdum libero, luctus ultrices ante. Nam vitae justo in nisi tempor mollis. Donec pharetra laoreet felis, in lacinia odio dignissim vitae. Phasellus aliquet, lectus id dignissim lobortis, lectus ipsum mollis massa, vitae semper magna ligula et sapien. Fusce interdum nibh ut purus vehicula porttitor. Vivamus et ante ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis sagittis elit. Curabitur bibendum suscipit enim, consequat varius ante pretium at. Vestibulum malesuada, est eu egestas dapibus, justo odio feugiat sem, id mollis metus est luctus risus. Maecenas vitae purus nulla. Vestibulum eu dolor vel nunc iaculis mollis. Curabitur at eros aliquet, sodales nunc sed, fringilla quam. Aenean odio felis, porta in bibendum vitae, mollis in est. Nam nisi risus, volutpat eu pharetra vel, scelerisque at mauris.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/pooJRNL)

but the element kind flickers during the scroll. My guess is because the `transform: translateY()` is being modified so frequently (although i kinda thought that was part of the main reason for using `requestAnimationFrame()`... to be sure the browser only made the updates when it could handle it). I know removing the the `transition` from the CSS will stop this but then I lose my "chase" effect.

Is there any way to set a delay as I could with `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`... or is there a different way I should be going about achieving that effect? or if not, can anything be done about the flickering or is that just the nature of the beast?

Comment: Why use script to position an element "sticky", when you can do `position: sticky` with CSS? ... or using any other CSS option, which might differ based on what you really is trying to do.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean with "flickering"? ... that it doesn't stay still while scrolling?

Comment: @LGSon - `position: sticky` doesn't produce the effect of the element chasing (or lagging slightly behind) the scroll. I'm going for the illusion that the floating element is actually "moving" and not just staying in a fixed position as the rest of the window scrolls. By "flcikering, I mean that it's not transitioning smoothly from 1 position to the next. Thx for the other info.

Comment: Okay, well, for me the transition moves smoothly, and if you increase the `duration` (to e.g. 300ms), it shows more clearly.

Comment: **MUCH** smoother at 300ms duration. Any idea what difference that extra 50ms makes?

Comment: re: throttling, from the example at the link provided, that's exactly what I thought I was doing with my `ticking = ticking || requestAnimationFrame(() => {...})`. Is that not accurate?

Comment: Dave - "throttling": correct, should have been more clear, as I referred to the sample later in that link, which use `setTimeout` instead. -- "timeout": primarily because the transition is supposed to last longer, hence starts up slower.

Comment: Is my answer good enough for an upvote, or just not useful?

Comment: wow. +1. sorry, this sprint's code-freeze and real life have been getting in the way. Useful, not ideal/perfect for this scenario. Thanks for the followup.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use requestAnimationFrame when you use css transitions, they are already handled during "animation frame". just add delay to `transitionDelay`:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var top = window.scrollY;
    console.log(top);
    box.style.transform = 'translateY(' + top + 'px)';
    box.style.transition = 'all 100ms ease-out 1s';
});
```

the box is flickering because it's jumping by just several pixels and already eases out before you scroll to the next point

Comment: Good to know about not needing `requestAnimationFrame` when using transitions. I was hoping it waited until it finishes 1 transition before starting the next... to whatever new position happens to be appropriate at that point in time. I guess that's actually maybe what it's doing with the delay? The only problem is that can be scrolled off the top of the viewport with the delay added (even when i dropped it down to 100ms - same as duration) and doesn't come back into view until the scrolling stops. I'm trying to keep it in view the entire time. Are transitions maybe not the right way to go?